# Js File Not Updated in Chrome, After I publish website.How to Deal with it?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, jquery-ui-datepicker

Hello StackOverflow ppl I got Problem with javascript file in ASP MVC Website.

I am using jquery Datepickers, which i have in my core.js file.

When i updated jquery Datepicker dateformat to 'dd/mm/yy', in my core.js and uploaded web site on IIS. Users See Old DateFormats in **CHROME**. (Problem not exists in Firefox or IE.just one refresh helps.)

In Chrome I Cleaned Cache and problem was gone but i cant tell 3000 users one by one to clean cache...

Any Solutions?

Comment: Give you script a version number so it uses the new version

Comment: Shift+F5 works. It ignores cached content on refresh

Comment: And Guys When Chrome Will Automaticly Get New Js version If I will not change anything now??

Comment: Liam Sorry I Didnt Knew that i can give version name to Js file.

Comment: Rima as I said I cant tell 3000 ppl to Make Shift+f5.:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another good solution to trick any browsers that don't like to listen to `cache expiration` is to make it append something like `?v=versionumber` to the js URL as the browser will treat this like a new URL.

So in other words every time you make changes increment the version number it appends and this will ensure that browsers re-download the JavaScript.

Example:

`someURL/js/jquery.js?v=3.1.1`

If you updates would change to:

`someURL/js/jquery.js?v=3.1.2`

Comment: Tnx I will Try your Solution.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to specify the `cache expiration` with whatever caching agent your using.

Answer (score 0):

The browser might be caching the JS/CSS files etc and you need to set the meta tag for cache clearance

Examples:

```
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1910 4:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```